# GA4 Relative Outbound Link Tracking with a redirect

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to track outbound links with GA4. My link structure is like . I want to capture how many people clicked /cgi-bin/abdl.cgi?abc.com
and date.

Comment: Show your link structure. Also show the html and a screenshot of the clicked element value from the GTM debugger.

Comment: <a href="/cgi-bin/abdl.cgi?abc.com">abc</a>. So when someone click on this link I want to capture link and number of times link is hit.

Comment: and you're using GTM?

Comment: I am using only Analytics 4. I have not added GTM to my site. I am able to track outbound links and affiliate links using GA4 as per description given on analyticsmania.

Comment: you will need some custom tracking here. The library is not gonna do the heavy lifting for you. Either you do it with GTM and a bit of JS, or you do it with no GTM and more JS.

Comment: That is not an outbound link as it is on the same domain, so the GA4 mechanism for tracking outbound clicks will not catch it. It also currently does not seem to deal with links that don't contain a target="_blank" which makes it easier to track links like that via an onclick.

I presume the link is its own tracking link that redirects to abc.com. Maybe adding a target="_blank" and an onclick that sends an event including abc.com would do the trick.